# How to return object or view from same ControllerAdvice method?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm setting a method handles exception and I want to return object if it's a ajax request. If it's not, I want to return view in my spring boot web application. It successfully returns view but when it returns object, response is a stack about exception had thrown.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GenericExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    protected Object handleConflict(RuntimeException ex, WebRequest request) {

    if (isAjaxRequest(request)) {
        AjaxResult aResult = new AjaxResult();
        aResult.setStatus(Status.ERROR);
        aResult.setMessage(NoticeMessages.ERROR);
        return aResult;
    }
        return "503";

    }

    private boolean isAjaxRequest(WebRequest request) {
        return "XMLHttpRequest".equals(request.getHeader("X-Requested-With"));
    }

}
```

Comment: And what is the exception?

Comment: It returns this json which is not the AjaxResult object that i ve return {"timestamp":1549641839921,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"No message available","path":"/signup"}

Comment: Hi @John, welcome to SO. It is a good practice to include your error or exception log in the body of your question.

Comment: You're taking over the responsibilities of `BasicErrorController` and should probably read its logic. More generally, handling `Exception` instead of something more specific like `NotFoundException` doesn't give you a lot of room for customizing your response logic.

Comment: @chrylis actually its what i want. If there is an exception that im not handling, i want to just return basic 503 if its not a ajax request. And return a ajaxresult object if its ajax request.

Comment: Hi @MostafaArianNejad. There is no error log because the problem is not an exception had thrown. Problem is spring doesnt return the ajaxresult that i have. Instead it returns another response that i shared as json above.

Comment: So read `BasicErrorController`.